# What is error In this Java Inventory Management System Code?

Tags: java, mysql

```
private void cmbProductItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    if (cmbProduct.getSelectedIndex() > 0) {
        Connection con = null;
        CallableStatement cstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = DatabaseHelper.getConnection();
            cstmt = con.prepareCall("{?=call getProductQty(?)}");
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            cstmt.setString(2, cmbProduct.getSelectedItem().toString());
            cstmt.execute();
            int output = cstmt.getInt(1);
            lblQty.setText(String.valueOf(output));
            cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call avg_price(getProductId(?)}");
            cstmt.setString(1, cmbProduct.getSelectedItem().toString());
            cstmt.execute();
            rs = cstmt.getResultSet();
            while (rs.next()) {
                lblPrice.setText(rs.getString(1));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
                cstmt.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am making a Java Inventory Management System. Currently I am in the data fetching process from the database. I have written code in the cmbProductItemStateChanged event of ComboBox. There is no syntax error.
getProductQty and getProductId are a function. avg_price is a procedure.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.execute(CallableStatement.java:920)
at IMS.Inventory.cmbProductItemStateChanged(Inventory.java:242)
at IMS.Inventory.access$000(Inventory.java:19)
at IMS.Inventory$1.itemStateChanged(Inventory.java:75)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1223)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1271)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1330)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:118)
at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:93)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:576)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:622)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicComboPopup.java:852)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(BasicComboPopup.java:501)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at IMS.Inventory.cmbProductItemStateChanged(Inventory.java:254)
at IMS.Inventory.access$000(Inventory.java:19)
at IMS.Inventory$1.itemStateChanged(Inventory.java:75)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1223)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1271)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1330)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:118)
at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:93)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:576)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:622)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicComboPopup.java:852)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(BasicComboPopup.java:501)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: The obvious first thing to check is your syntax for the prepare call stmt. Seems to be what the error is telling you.

Comment: what's wrong in syntax?

Comment: the getProductQty SQL code worked fine but avg_price SQL code showed error why?

Comment: Name of above file is Inventory.java

Comment: You are missing closing bracket: `avg_price(getProductId(?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a closing parenthesis missing:

```
cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call avg_price(getProductId(?))}");
                                                        ^ (added)
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you